# Objectify @Parent annotation vs Ref

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm creating a pseudo social network like Facebook posts and wall using Datastore and Objectify when I try to load a user wall I find all `Posts` related to `User` using key and find the `Posts` related to friends and finally show the wall.

The problem is the task take so much time every time... I have a possible solution:

Add @Parent annotation to `Posts` related to user and when the user publish a new post create the entity and put to Datastore and:

1. Create a copy of this post with @Parent as each friend?
2. Create a ref key of recently created post and insert as new Post with @Parent as each friend?

What would be the best solution? My application is so slow because the Datastore queries of user friend posts.

Comment: `@Parent` makes those posts all part of the user's [entitiy group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002887/google-app-engine-entity-groups) which would probably limit you too much, that 1 update per entity group per second update limit in particular may be not enough for many people posting on a single user's wall.

Comment: I made the assumption that you mean "objectify" instead of "objetify", feel free to correct if I'm wrong.